# How to customize json_encode data in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a MySQL database table named `questions` having the following columns:

`id, question, category, type, difficulty, correct_answer, incorrect_answer_1, incorrect_answer_2, incorrect_answer_3`

I need to output data from this table into `JSON` format but in the following specific format only (like incorrect answers clubbed together):

```
{
  "response_code": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "Science & Nature",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "hard",
      "question": "An organic compound is considered an alcohol if it has what functional group?",
      "correct_answer": "Hydroxyl",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Carbonyl",
        "Alkyl",
        "Aldehyde"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "easy",
      "question": "Which of the following is not a faction in Tom Clancy&#039;s The Division?",
      "correct_answer": "CDC",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Cleaners",
        "Last Man Batallion",
        "Rikers"
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Entertainment: Video Games",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "Which of the following Call of Duty games was a PS3 launch title?",
      "correct_answer": "Call of Duty 3",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare",
        "Call of Duty: World at War",
        "Call of Duty: Roads to Victory"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

With the basic knowledge of PHP and `json_encode`, I can output the data in JSON format, but unable to output it in the above-mentioned format. My PHP code is:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "demo_db");
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions limit 50");
$statement->execute(); 
$result = $statement->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($outp); // Tried this, but it's not outputting in desired format

//echo json_encode(($result->fetch_assoc())); // Tried this, but it's also not outputting in desired format
//echo json_encode(($result->fetch_array())); // Tried this, but it's also not outputting in desired format
```

I have tried three different ways to use `json_encode`, but I couldn't make the desired format, especially, making the incorrect answers a nested array-like format.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to retrieve the rows in the result set one at a time (in a `while` loop, for example) and then transform the retrieved row into the format that you want and add it to an `output` variable.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "demo_db");

$sql = "
    SELECT
        id,
        question,
        category,
        type,
        difficulty,
        correct_answer,
        incorrect_answer_1,
        incorrect_answer_2,
        incorrect_answer_3
    FROM questions
    Limit 50
";

$query  = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();

$output = [];


// Loop through the result set row by row
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output[] = [
        "category"          => $row["category"],
        "type"              => $row["type"],
        "difficulty"        => $row["difficulty"],
        "question"          => $row["question"],
        "correct_answer"    => $row["correct_answer"],
        "incorrect_answers" => [
            $row["incorrect_answer_1"],
            $row["incorrect_answer_2"],
            $row["incorrect_answer_3"],
        ],
    ];
}

// Convert to JSON and print
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: thank you `"incorrect_answers" => [$row["incorrect_answer_1"],...` This is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

You have fields in the wanted output, which are not returned in the results, so you have to build by yourself.

***This only a guided answer!** *This will not produce the complete output!* You have to process the details by yourself, especially for `incorrect_answers`*.

```php
$results = [
    'response_code' => 0,
    'results' => []
];

foreach($outp as $item) {
    $results['results'][] = $item;
}

echo json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. I have also thought of adding hard-coded values for `response_code`. But like you mentioned `$results[]=$item`, it don't add values inside `result`, instead, it outputs like (adding extra number before json objects) - `"{response_code": 0, "results": [], "0": { "id": 1...}, "1":{"id": 2...)`

Comment: My bad, I misspelled. Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the formatting recommendation. That makes sense.